# yum finding the parents of a dependent rpm

Tags: yum, dependencies

Running RHEL 7.9.  I have `tomcat-servlet-3.0-api-7.0.76-16.el7_9.noarch` showing up via an `rpm -qa`

How can I use `yum` or anything else to find why I have that tomcat-servlet installed and what rpm's are using that as a dependency?

I want to know how or why `tomcat-servlet-3.0-api-7.0.76-16.el7_9.noarch` got installed in the first place, because I know I did not explicitly install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in `rpm -qa | grep tomcat` ; do echo "Package [$i]:"; rpm -q --requires $i ; echo ; done
```

This will show all tomcat packages and what required this one to be installed. You can trace the output contents